# How to only render modal in the initial route of the stacknavigator?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

The initial screen of my stacknavigator has a modal that shows up upon the occurrence of a certain event ... problem is when I navigate to other screens the modal still shows up when the event is triggered. I want it only to show up when the initial route is showing up.

Comment: At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: @FrankerZ Thank you for your reply. If I have done more research and found anything that goes along with my case I wouldn't be asking about it. So if you are more fortunate to stumble by any links to similar issues or know how to do fix it yourself, it is definitely going to be more useful than instructing me to read about how to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check `this.props.navigation.state.routeName` so that you know if it's initial screen or not.

I got this from this document.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-prop

Comment: Thank you Mr. Lee for your answer but unfortunately it didn't work. When you check the routeName in the screen where the modal renders, it always returns the screen name not the screen that is currently displaying

Comment: @AhmedSamy Ah, now I got your question. hm... then, you can switch it to off before navigating next screen. But you want to better solution, don't you?

Comment: Actually I managed to accomplish the task using redux ... but your comment just gave an idea of a much simpler solution but too late to change the whole thing back now but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

How about using state?

```
import React, { useEffect,useState } from "react";

const MainScreen = (props) => {
  const [seenReminder, setReminder] = useState(false);
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    if (!seenReminder){
      props.navigation.navigate('reminder')
      setReminder(true)
    }
  }, [seenReminder]);

  return (
    <View ></View>
  );
};
export default MainScreen;
```